# Chemisorption vs Physisorption?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, electrochemistry

What is the fundamental difference between chemical adsorption and physical adsorption.

Why do some compounds chemisorb and others physisorb?

Comment: It's the difference between binding to an adsorbent chemically (undergoing a chemical reaction) vs simply binding through attraction, i.e. electrostatic attraction.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be one of degrees of bonding, without a clear distinction. As stated in [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physisorption#cite_note-1):

> Physisorption, also called physical adsorption, is a process in which
>   the electronic structure of the atom or molecule is barely perturbed
>   upon adsorption.$\mathrm{^{[1][2][3]}}$

A more thorough description is given later in the article:

> "The fundamental interacting force of physisorption is caused by van
>   der Waals force.   [...]   In comparison with chemisorption, in which
>   the electronic structure of bonding atoms or molecules is changed and
>   covalent or ionic bonds form, physisorption, generally speaking, can
>   only be observed in the environment of low temperature (thermal energy
>   at room temperature ~26 meV) and the absence of the relatively strong
>   chemisorptions. In practice, the categorisation of a particular
>   adsorption as physisorption or chemisorption depends principally on
>   the binding energy of the adsorbate to the substrate."

1) *K. Oura; et al. (2003), Surface Science, An Introduction, Berlin: Springer, ISBN 978-3-540-00545-2*
2) *M. C. Desjonqueres; et al. (1996. Corrected printing 1998), Concepts in surface physics (2nd ed.), New York: Springer-Verlag, ISBN 3-540-58622-9*
3) *Hans Luth; et al. (1993), Surfaces and interfaces of solids, Springer-Verlag, ISBN 978-3-540-56840-7*